# How to validate the status changes using Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a test wherein, the websockets sends messages to UI within given time. Say for example, after click of a button the status of a delivery would be "Committed" and then the status will change to "ETA scheduled" within 2 mins and then to final status "Delivered" within 3 mins.

I have used the below code but it keeps failing as its not waiting for the "Delivered" status.

```
cy.get('[data-testid="DeliveryItem"]')
  .last()
  .find('[data-testid="delivery-status"]', { timeout: 600000 })
  .contains("ETA")
  .parent()
  .should("have.text", "Delivered");
```

Is there a way to add timeout after ETA like we add to .get or .find?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try use cy.wait:

```
cy.get('[data-testid="DeliveryItem"]')
.last()
.wait(60000)
.find('[data-testid="delivery-status"]')
.contains("ETA")
.parent()
.should("have.text", "Delivered");
```

Comment: AssertionError Timed out retrying: "expected <p> to have text Delivered, but the text was ETA" message was received

Comment: Oh yes the wait should be after find maybe cy.get('[data-testid="DeliveryItem"]')
.last()
.find('[data-testid="delivery-status"]').wait(60000)
.contains("ETA")
.parent()
.should("have.text", "Delivered");